# running application it's showing this error in android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Hi In My Application Running it's not taking spaces.can anyone please help me

example: kkavitha rao not storing into database with out space it's storing into database

```
final String queryString = "student_name="
                                + student_name[k] + "&roll_no="+ roll_no[k];
    if(queryString!=""){
                    url = "http://75.125.237.76/android_connect/"+phpScript+".php?"+queryString;    
                }else{
                    url = "http://75.125.237.76/android_connect/"+phpScript+".php"; 
                }



 09-24 03:41:43.717: E/Fail 1(2073): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at 
 09-24 03:41:43.717: E/Fail 2(2073): java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
```

Comment: Please provide some code and background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `URLEncoder` to encode your URL params such as `student_name[k]` and `roll_no[k]`:

```
final String queryString =
    "student_name=" + URLEncoder.encode(student_name[k], "UTF-8")
    + "&roll_no="+ URLEncoder.encode(roll_no[k], "UTF-8");
```

Use `equals()` and not `==` or `!=` for comparing `String`s:

```
if(!"".equals(queryString))
```

Comment: can you please tel me how to use this one

Comment: Consider posting more of your stacktrace and code then.